# How to create an sql string to count selected rows with group by

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I am trying to query a mysql database with columns AUTHOR, TITLE, TEXT to count all instances of texts by a given title, grouped by an author, e.g. 
my table look like this
[image]

If my parameter is "Great Expectations", there are 2 entries of Great Expectaions by Dickens and 1 entry of Great Expectaions some Kathy Acker.

```
[{author=Charles Dickens, title=Great Expectations, count=2}, {author=Kathy Ackers, title=Great Expectations, count=1}]
```

So far I have come up with this string:

```
 jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT author, title, COUNT(*) as count FROM Quote GROUP BY author")
```

It somehow works but returns the counts of all entries by author in the database and all of my attempts to refine the search have failed.

I thought to include ...WHERE title = "Great Expectations"... but it does not work.

Comment: What is your database ?

Comment: it is mysql....

Comment: What do you do with the TEXT column and why do you mention it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restrict the aggregation to only books entitled "The Lost World":

```
jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT author, COUNT(*) AS count FROM Quote WHERE title = 'The Lost World' GROUP BY author")
```

Actually, your current query would only work on a few databases, such as MySQL or SQLite, because of the `GROUP BY` issue.  Here is the raw query:

```
SELECT author, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM Quote
WHERE title = 'The Lost World'
GROUP BY author;
```

Comment: but this is still returning all entries from the database (just in different order). What I need is to return only counts of texts for the title "The Lost World" distinguished by the names of different authors. I thought to include "WHERE title = "The Lost World" but for some reason this throws error.

Comment: @krenkz Sorry, I misunderstood your question.  I think you only need to add a `WHERE` clause restricting the query to the title "The Lost World."

Comment: I think it is my fault - nobody seems to understand what I want ... I will edit the question to explain myself properly.

Comment: I disagree, and I think the latest edit of my answer will give you the result set you want.

Comment: this is the query 
`jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT author, COUNT(*) as count FROM Quote WHERE title = Great Expectations GROUP BY author, title"));`
 and this is the error message
`Exception: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT author, COUNT(*) as count FROM Quote WHERE title = Great Expectations GROUP BY author, title]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Expectations GROUP BY author' at line 1`

Comment: That's not what my answer says `:-)` ... maybe you need to reload your page.

Comment: aaah...my bad...I always hated punctuation....works now just fine ....thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for ?
It is hard to understand from your question what is in your text field ? What kind of data?
What do you counting ?
My understanding is this:

```
SELECT author, title, ROUND ((LENGTH(text) - LENGTH(REPLACE(text, 
                            title, "") )) / LENGTH(title))  AS count
FROM Quote
```

Then you can add this to select only the title you need:

```
where title = 'The Lost World'
```

So you get this:

```
SELECT author, title, ROUND ((LENGTH(text) - LENGTH(REPLACE(text, 
                            title, "") ) 
        ) / LENGTH(title)        
    )  AS count
FROM Quote
where title = 'The Lost World'
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0bdd369143b1171802de0750ea9ce3e2)

Reading your question second time I see you maybe need this:

```
SELECT author, title, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM Quote 
where title = 'The Lost World'
GROUP BY author, title
```

or like this:

```
jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT author, title, COUNT(*) as count FROM Quote 
where title = 'The Lost World'
GROUP BY author, title")
```

Comment: Hi @krenkz , you are welcome. I am happy to help. Do you know you can give an up vote to the helpful answer ?